# How can I render html that contains script tag in Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have a Table that have Html Field
this field contains Html tags + script tag like this

```
<p class="alert alert-danger">some text </p>
<script>
alert("Hello world");
</script>
```

I'm using Blazor wasm and
I want to run the js code and show alert when I render the field content  (tags and scripts)
when I show it in the page

```
<div>
@((markupstring)Html)
</div>
@code{
[Parameter] public string Html {get; set;}

}
```

I tried to run this code
The html codes rendered but script codes don't invoke.

Comment: Which component is the top code block in?

Comment: The component's name is "PanelShow". It's a normal component in Blazor.
The Html Parameter in above is: 
 public string Html {get; set;} ="<p class="alert alert-danger">some text </p>
<script>
alert("Hello world");
</script>"

Answer (score 1):

You can't include script blocks within components like you have.

To run some JS you need to use JSInterop through the `IJSRuntime` service.

Here's your code that does pop up the alert.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime _js

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@Html

@code {
    private RenderFragment Html => (__builder) =>
        {
            <p class="alert alert-danger">some text </p>
            {_js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "HelloWorld"); }
        };
}
```

You should review the following section on MS Help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thank you for above answer
I have used IJsruntime, it only can invoke voids and functions. but sometimes we have declares , properties and object in js code that IJSruntime can't invoke it
Like
var data = new Array();
data[0] = '25';
function showData(){console.table(data[0])};

Comment: Write you code as functions in a JS file that you include in _Host,shtml or index.htm and then call them when you need to from your code.

Comment: Finally I did so and it worked.
thank you